# Process and return documents in Firestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Salutations! I'm trying to build a Cloud Function that gets Firestore data, extracts the most critical parts, and sends that to a client. So far I have:

```
exports.fun = functions.https.onRequest((rq, rs) => {
  tokensRef = db.collections('token');
  listsRef = db.collections('list');
  async_part = async () => {
    var snapshots = await Promise.all([ tokensRef.get(), listsRef.get()]);
    tokensQuerySnapshot = snapshots[0];
    listsQuerySnapshot = snapshots[1];
    var t = {};
    var l = {};
    tokensQuerySnapshot.forEach( (doc) => {
      t[doc.id] = doc.data().calls;
    });
    listsQuerySnapshot.docs.forEach( (doc) => {
      l[doc.id] = doc.data().calls;
    });
```

At this line, I have two options. This option sends `{lists:{}, tokens:{}}` to the client, despite `console.log` suggesting it ought to be working:

```
    // prints {lists: {id1: data1,...}, tokens: {id1: data1,...}}
    console.log({lists: l, tokens: t})
    // sends {lists: {}, tokens: {}}
    rs.status(200).send({lists: l, tokens: t})
```

This option cuts out all of the server-side processing, but does send data to the client:

```
    // sends {lists: [[id, data],...], tokens: [[id, data],...]}
    rs.status(200).send({lists: listsQuerySnapshot.docs.map((a) => [a.id, a.data()]),
      tokens: tokensQuerySnapshot.docs.map((a)=>[a.id, a.data()])
    });
```

I suspect I'm still misunderstanding something about how the code handles promises. Any ideas about how I can make sure the response is not sent before the data is ready, and thus get my processing code to work?

Thank you!

Comment: There's not enough information here.  Please edit the question to show the [complete minimal function](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that doesn't work the way you expect, and explain what it is actually doing instead.  There should be enough information that someone could copy the code and observe the same result.  Include the output of any debug logs that help illustrate the way it executes.

Comment: @DougStevenson Done! :)

Comment: That doesn't look like complete code to me.  You just have some code fragments.

Comment: The entire function is there. The first part, plus either of the second two parts, makes the function that gives the behaviour indicated in the code.

Comment: OK, what is your log output when you run this? How is the result different than what you expect?  We should be able to reproduce the behavior you describe.  Note that w can't see the contents of your database, so we don't know what your queries should generate.

Comment: As indicated in the question - the response data is the object with correct keys but empty objects as values in the first option. In the second option, the values are a list of [id, data] pairs as expected (but I can't work out how to do any processing on that data). I would expect the values in the first option to be an {id: data} object but the objects are empty, even though console.log spits out correct values when I log the response before sending it.

Comment: It generally helps to show the specific data that you're working with.